# According to LDS (Mormon) teaching, what is the relationship between Jesus and Lucifer?

Tags: lds, satan, christology

What does the LDS/Mormon church teach about the relationship between Jesus and Lucifer? Are they beings on the same level or of the same origin? What are their natures? What texts are used to teach specifically about the relationship between them?

Comment: Why the background statement on mainline Christianity? If this is a question about LDS doctrine, why not just ask it about LDS doctrine without framing the question as pitting one tradition against another?

Comment: @Caleb I hoped to give a framework for an answer.  That's all.  I didn't know how else to frame the question in order to get answers that were narrow enough in scope.

Comment: I don't see how adding content about the beliefs of other traditions help make this a more narrow question other than only bringing out any conflicting issues. I think it would be just as useful and less non-constructive to just ask about the teachings you want to know about without putting them on the defensive against another teaching.

Comment: @Caleb Cool... wasn't trying to put anyone on the defensive.

Comment: *Please see [this question](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/31389/bishops-have-no-free-will) for the logic behind my response.* Your question should be down voted for "lack of research with some other translations first" - **per Wikis**.  "A) Use a Bible in a language you speak and B) use a dictionary. Either or both of those things would save you from this sort of misunderstanding." - **per Caleb**.  Lucifer isn't the devil or Satan.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The LDS theological view is that God, the Eternal Father, created all spirits, including Jesus the Firstborn, Lucifer, and all the rest of us, as His spirit children. Further, God is a separate being from Jesus and the Holy Ghost, who are all individual personages.

These three beings constitute the *godhead*, which is different from the usual Trinity belief.

These teachings are in harmony with at least the following scriptures:

- [Col. 1:15](http://lds.org/scriptures/nt/col/1.15?lang=eng#14) (Jesus the Firstborn of every creature, image of the Father)
- [Isaiah 14:12-14](http://lds.org/scriptures/ot/isa/14.12-14?lang=eng#12) (Lucifer-son of the morning-rebellion)
- [D&C 76:25-27](http://lds.org/scriptures/dc-testament/dc/76.25-27?lang=eng#24) (Lucifer, an angel in the authority of God, fell)
- [D&C 93:21](http://lds.org/scriptures/dc-testament/dc/93.21?lang=eng#20) (Jesus is the Firstborn)
- [Moses 4:1-4](http://lds.org/scriptures/pgp/moses/4.1-4?lang=eng#0) (God tells Moses what happened in the pre-mortal life with Lucifer)

For context: there was a council in heaven regarding God's plan for all His spirit children. God's plan was presented, and a Savior was needed to fulfill it. Jesus was Chosen by the Father to fulfill that role.

Satan opposed, declaring *his* plan, which was contrary to the will of the Father. [War ensued](http://lds.org/scriptures/nt/rev/7?lang=eng) between "the dragon" (Satan) and the Christ's followers, which war is still ongoing today, here in mortality. It's a sibling rivalry, if you will, which Jesus and His disciples will win in the end.

Comment: I want to be clear, I'm not LDS, but I gave this an upvote. I think answer is clear and shows how the LDS understand the relationship between Jesus and Lucifer.  When voting, please keep in mind we look for good explanations, not whether we agree with the explanation.

Comment: So, what specifically is the relationship betweeen Jesus and Lucifer?

Comment: @Narnian: The same as the relationship between Jesus and any of God's other children.  This answer makes that quite clear.

Comment: @MasonWheeler So, does the LDS church teach that Jesus is one of God's children?  Or one of His creations?

Comment: @Narnian Both. Parents create children.

Comment: @Matt I see what you're saying, but I think "creating" something and "fathering" can be two very distinct things.  Creating something does not require reproduction, while father "is" reproduction.

Comment: @Narnian: I believe what Matt's trying to say is that the LDS church teaches that Jesus is one of God's children, just as we are, but that from the LDS perspective the distinction you're trying to draw between "children of God" and "creations of God" is not as significant as you think it is.  (Specifically as it relates to his children. This is not to say that His other creations, such as the animals, are God's literal offspring in the same way as humans are.)

Comment: @AffableGeek I can't agree with your comment. I would hope that the answers here are not only clear but also accurate and that upvotes should also reflect that.

Answer (score 6):

The LDS church teaches that Christ, Lucifer, and all beings that live know, have lived and will live here are God's spirit children.  That makes Christ and Lucifer brothers, and all of us their siblings.

Before we came to earth God asked one of His children to play the role of a savior.  That person would have to carry out the atonement so that both justice and mercy could be satisfied.

There were two volunteers. Jesus Christ was willing to obey God's plan. This plan allows the rest of us to choose whether or not we would follow God's commandments and give the glory to God.

Lucifer wanted to force us to obey the commandments and he wanted the glory for himself.  One third of God's children wanted it Satan's way and a war broke out.

Lucifer and his followers were cast out and not allowed to gain a body and live a life on earth.

So the LDS church teaches that Lucifer is our spiritual brother and Christ's as well.  That doesn't mean that he has our best interests in mind.  He's jealous of our physical bodies and the experiences we get to have and so he and his followers try to get us to abuse the bodies we have.