# What does the Church of Jesus Christ of Latter-Day Saints teach about who Jesus is and where He came from?

Tags: lds, christology

From the [answer to another question](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/5502/207), someone suggested that the LDS (Mormon) church teaches that Jesus is distinct from God—that though He is a part of the Godhead, the Godhead is not a Trinity defined by the "Three-in-One" idea.

What specifically, then, does the LDS Church teach about who Jesus is and where He came from?  Is He eternal, not eternal, uncreated, created?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The below is pulled from [The Araonic Priesthood Manual 3: Lesson 1 The Godhead](http://www.lds.org/manual/aaronic-priesthood-manual-3/lesson-1-the-godhead?lang=eng)

> Jesus Christ is—
>
> 1. The Firstborn Son of Heavenly Father in the spirit.
> 2. The Only Begotten Son of Heavenly Father in the flesh.
> 3. The Creator of heaven and earth under Heavenly Father’s direction.
> 4. The Savior and Redeemer of mankind.

1. Mormons believe we are all the spirit children of Heavenly Father, Jesus is our older brother in spirit.
2. Kind of self explanatory
3. If the Godhead means 3 distinct Individuals, one of them was responsible for the physical creation of the earth. Going further on this point would be a whole different answer.
4. This is, as far as I know, the common denominator among all christian denominations.

So that is who the Mormons believe he is, as far as created, Mormons believe all spirits are created, thus given #1 above, Heavenly Father Created Jesus. I would like to note though that from what I have learned the definition of Created to a Mormon is a bit different than to many other christian groups.

As far as eternal, [President Ezra Taft Benson](http://www.lds.org/liahona/1992/04/life-is-eternal?lang=eng&query=spirits+eternal) 13th President of the LDS Church said `"Life is eternal. We are eternal beings."` If we are eternal then Jesus is Eternal.

Answer (score 9):

I agree with @Matt's comment. And from what I understand, LDS believe that all people, angels (including Lucifer and co.), and even Jesus were *created* by God and are His children and existed and lived with God before creation in what they call the "pre-earth" life, and that Jesus was *chosen* to be Savior in this pre-earth life. Also, in our "pre-earth" life we (the people) all had faith in Jesus. They believe God sent us to Earth to learn to make the right choices, and by choosing to have faith in Jesus, *again*, can we return home to the father.

The belief that Jesus was created would mean He is not eternal, and is not God, as defined by the trinity belief, but perhaps *a god*.

[Here](http://lds.org/plan/our-eternal-life) is a link for more info (Thanks @Matt).

Comment: I don't know for sure but you might be confusing the Jehovah's Witnesses with the LDS.

Comment: @nickecarlo No, I've spoken with LDS elders before and this is the doctrine they presented. They gave me a pamphlet that goes over this. I can quote it later when I get home if you'd like.

Comment: That would be nice or maybe a link that everyone can go to and see the information as coming from them.

Comment: @nickecarlo No, that is LDS belief. Those who chose to follow Christ (and thus the Father) come to Earth, gain physical bodies, and prove themselves and learn and grow. Those who followed Satan in the pre-earth life forfeited that blessing and are servants of the devil. Their official website explains this more: http://lds.org/plan/our-eternal-life (see all the links on the left side)

Comment: @ Shredder I have removed my downvote because of the link provided by Matt. Please add this information in the answer.

Answer (score 7):

Mormons believe that that Jesus Christ is the only begotten Son of God in the flesh. At the same time He is the first spirit child of our Heavenly Father. Our spirits are also spirit children of our Heavenly Father according to Mormon doctrine. Therefore, we are all children of our Heavenly Father in the spirit (Heb 12:9). In this sense we are all brother and sisters and Jesus is our elder brother in the spirit.

Mormons believe that the universe and everything in it has an eternal existence and everything has been created from something. (The universe didn't just pop up out of nothing.) Therefore the creation is rather a question of organization. This also applies to our spirits and the spirit of Jesus. In this sense, Jesus is eternal and the spirits of mankind are also eternal. We all have been created from spiritual matter which is in LDS terms sometimes referred to as *intelligence*.

As Jesus plays the special role of being the only begotten Son, He inherited some traits from our Father in Heaven, such as power over death and knowing all things (as is evident from the new testament). Before He came to this earth and received a mortal body, Jesus existed in a premortal existence as everyone of us did. In this premortal existance He created the earth and the rest of the universe under the direction of God, the Eternal Father. Jesus Christ is considered the Jehova of the Old Testament by latter-day saints. In many (most) instances, it is Jesus acting in proxy for our Heavenly Father.

However, Jesus Christ and our Heavenly Father are distinct being with different roles but with the same goal and purpose which is the eternal wellfare of the souls of mankind. The role of our Heavenly Father is He is the Eternal Parent of our spirits, that He is the director of all things (though delegating many things to His Only Begotten). The role of Jesus is that of a mediator who atoned for the sins of mankind to blot our all our transgressions against the law of God.

There is a good [talk by an apostle of the Church of Jesus Christ of Latter-Day Saints about this topic here.](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GzE6QFj6maQ)

Comment: Welcome to Christianity.SE, Ralph, and thanks for contributing, especially for answering the question on-topic.

Comment: Was surprised by the words of video behind link which received. Also it felt that it was said with authority. Maybe LDS is apostolic and biblical denomination? They add new details without refuting classic christian doctrines like trinity and open canon - principle, which seems that classical christianity does not embrace. Also - because I like science fiction and LDS doctrine as I have read-it seems that LDS doctrine is appealing to me. Also teachings of IHOPKC are appealing to me. This is current opinion. It might change. Alsothey haven't altered KJV bible like Jehovas w. have. Comments?

Comment: @laovultai If you can form your comment into a specific, objective question which has actual answers (as opposed to opinions), feel free to post a question and contribute. (For non-Q&A discussion, try the chat instead.)

Comment: (The universe didn't just pop up out of nothing.)  Then, how do they explain Hebrews11:3 -  Through faith we understand that the worlds were framed by the word of God, so that things which are seen were not made out out of what was visible.