# What are the major differences between evangelical Christianity and Mormonism?

Tags: lds, evangelicalism

I'm looking for concrete theological beliefs and practices on where they differ. Christians say that Mormons aren't Christian and yet Mormons call themselves Christian. So it can be quite hard to tell for a everyday person who is who and what is what.

Comment: Welcome to the forum, Josh.  This question may be too broad to be answered.  There are differences between the two on the nature of God, salvation, the afterlife, recognized scriptures, etc.  If you can narrow the focus a bit, you may get a better answer.

Comment: In addition to what Narnian pointed out, there are a lot of questions on this topic that have already been asked and answered.  Have a look at the "lds" tag to see what our community has already covered, and if you find that you have a question on a subject that hasn't been asked yet, feel free to ask that.

Comment: Why do you focus your question on evangelical Christianity?

Comment: Just traditional Christianity is what I mean. I honestly don't know enough on how to ask the question properly. Also, Mason, I tried to find something similar, but could not.

Comment: Josh, Check [this question](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/10237/what-is-the-plan-of-salvation-in-lds-theology) out.  Soteriology is one of the starkest differences between the two, along with the theology of God. Also, you probably wont find an answer to the question of if Mormons are Christians or not because the [FAQ](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/faq) here states "any group that identifies themselves as Christian are to be considered on-topic and allowed to label themselves Christian."

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The "Evangelical" movement spreads across an incredibly wide range of beliefs, so it will be hard to nail this down, but a few things come to mind that ought to have broad acceptance and make at least some form of answer possible. For convenience in the rest of this answer, please treat the word "Evangelical" merely as broadly representing "Most Evangelicals".

- Mormons believe men can become Gods, or become like God on this earth. Evangelicals believe God is the singular, unique, and supreme being, and any human transcendence takes place after death or Jesus' return.
- Mormons see Jesus as a separate entity from God the Father. Evangelicals view God the Father and Jesus as parts of the same entity. It's hard to understate how important this point is, especially in light of the first point: the Mormon view withholds from Jesus some part of God's place as *the* unique divinity.
- Mormons believe a prophet lead a group of Jews out of Jerusalem to the New World (America) around 600BC, where for a time they flourished. Evangelicals do not.
- Mormons believe a prophet to that group created a certain set of gold tablets, which Joseph Smith later translated. Evangelicals believe these tablets are utter bunk.
- Mormons believe Jesus incarnate visited the North American Continent. Evangelicals do not.
- Mormons believe in the writings and teachings of Joseph Smith, that they are related directly or almost directly from God. Evangelicals believe Joseph Smith to be somewhere in between a deliberate con-artist, charlatan, and mentally unstable, and point to serious concerns over the credibility of Joseph Smith's claim to 8 witnesses.
- Mormons believe the Apostle John is still alive. Evangelicals (with some exception) do not.
- Yes, Mormons have allowed and supported polygamy. Evangelicals, at this time, do not, but there are places in the world and times in history where this does not hold.
- Mormons believe in something called Pre-mortal Life. Evangelicals do not.
- Mormons practice Baptism for the Dead. Evangelicals do not.
- Mormons practice a ritual known as "Endowments". Evangelicals do not.
- Mormons believe all men will come to glory, but non-believers will come to less glory than practicing Christians... but there is no hell. Evangelicals believe in eternal punishment for non-believers and all those who refuse to submit to the will of God.

The root question here, though, is whether or not Mormons are themselves even Christian. To understand this, you need to look at it from both sides. In a broad sense, for our purpose here one is a Christian when one acknowledges the person of Christ as their creator, savior, and Lord. Everything else — all the denominations, splits, and arguments — are just details.

With that in mind, the Non-mormon Christian perspective is that Mormons have been lead astray, and have allowed the teachings of Joseph Smith and his successors to supersede and in many cases replace those of Christ... and so they no longer follow Christ supremely, but (perhaps unwittingly) follow the teachings of Joseph Smith instead. Moreover, since Mormons refuse to grant Jesus full unity with God the Father, but hold him separate from God the Father, it is offensive to mainline Christians to watch Mormons hold up the teachings of Joseph Smith above or before the level of Christ, yet still use the name of Christ to describe themselves.

The Mormon perspective is Joseph Smith's teachings *are* Christ's teachings; Joseph Smith was merely His mouthpiece. They hold both the Old and New Testaments to be scripture (just not all scripture). To be considered "not Christian" is offensive to Mormons, because they still believe Christ died for their sins, just as "regular" Christians do.

Comment: Your second bullet point is incorrect.  Mormons hold a different view of the Godhead than the Trinitarian concept that Evangelicals believe, but in no way do they deny the divinity of Jesus.

Comment: @MasonWheeler if that's my only error in Mormon doctrine, I'll be very pleased with this. Corrected.

Comment: From my understanding they in no way hold up Joseph Smith to the Level of Christ. Also, Regardless of what some other answers here say, The only references I have found on their site point to Apostle John returning in a resurrected form, not having never died. I think it's worth noting that mormons do not currently practice polygamy anywhere, since some evangelicals did. (you might disagree about them being evangicals but some still do in Maine I think) I would also add that Mormons believe just about everyone is going to go to heaven, and evangelicals do not.

Comment: @MaskedPlant I don't think I claim mormons hold Joseph Smith on the same level as Christ, especially in light of the 2nd half of the first sentence of the last paragraph.

Comment: Makes sense, I was mostly referring to the last sentence of the second to last paragraph. So you're not saying that mormons hold him up next to Christ, you are saying mainline Christians watch mormons hold up Joseph Smith to the level of Christ.

Comment: @MaskedPlant exactly, not because Mormons see it that way, but because from the outsider perspective Joseph Smith's teachings supplant that of Jesus.

Comment: I always like your answers, but this is, by far, the best. Good answer!

Comment: One minor error in your last bullet point.  Latter-Day Saints do believe in Hell, in essentially the traditional sense, (a place of endless punishment for the wicked,) which they call Outer Darkness--a term used by the Savior a few times in his parables--but LDS theology holds that only those who have deliberately and knowingly committed extremely grave sins will be consigned to it. One has to know exactly what they're doing and what's at stake, and just not care, and choose to throw salvation away.  It's not something that, as Evangelicals hold, can happen if you just believe the wrong thing.

Comment: I've also heard that mormon's believe that Jesus and Satan are brothers!

Comment: @Matt, that is correct. Mormons believe that Jesus, Satan, Adam, you, me, Hitler, and Ghandi are spirit sons  of God the Father. This would make all of these "brothers". See also http://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/5490.

Comment: Hell is also believed in the form of what is called "Spirit Prison" But it is not believed to be without end. That is where people pay for their own sins if they didn't let Christ. but when they are paid for it will end. It is eternal in the sense that Eternal is a name for God. So Godly punishment, not necessarily without end. Following the paying for your own sins you would move into one of 3 heavens depending on your life. Celestial, Terestial, and Telestial(Glory of the sun, moon, or stars).

Comment: Why do you believe Joseph Smith was insane? Don't Evangelicals believe that a certain man was given the full revelation of God? Don't they believe that this man was able to expound and interpret the Scriptures with perfection? Before they quote this man, don't they say "This is what the word of God says"? Don't they believe this man had seen God, and God spoke to him? The only difference I see is that Joseph Smith claimed to have 8 witnesses, but this man only claimed to have two (zero eye-witnesses if we believe *Acts* 9 over *Acts* 22).

Comment: @anonymouswho The difference is Jesus was more than man.

Comment: Hello Joel. I was not talking about Yeshua. Although I do believe he was a man chosen and approved by God, I was talking about a different man.

Comment: If you mean the Pope, then, no, Evangelicals do not generally follow him at all (though there are a number of exceptions). Mainline Christianity has three major camps: Catholicism, Calvinistic Protestantism, and non-Calvinistic/Armenian Protestantism. The latter two do not follow the Pope, and it's from those two that the Evangelical movement mainly draws.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn Sorry I didn't realize you had written back. No, I'm not talking about the pope either.

Comment: Small point but I'd suggest removing the Israelites coming to America as an independent point. Its not a specifically Mormon idea. It was a common idea in Joseph Smith's time, that's where he got it. Many still believe there is historical truth to it even. But it's not a theological point until you bring in Jesus visiting then and leaving a revelation. Many evangelicals, Mormons and otherwise could agree with that bullet point alone.

Answer (score 8):

Simply put Evangelicals differ over at least three primary things:

**1. The Nature of Jesus**

Evangelicals believe Jesus to be God - of one being with Father, God from God, Light from Light, true God from true God, etc... [Mormons do not.](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/12151/1039) Mormons believe Jesus to be divine, but a separate person from the Father. Evangelicals tend to subscribe to the historic creeds of the church - Nicene, Apostles, etc... - and are almost invariably Trinitarian.  (I cannot say that I have *ever* run across a non-Trinitarian Evangelical, but as it is a movement and not a denomination, there are always exceptions).

<sup>Note: In the comments, there was a notion that the creeds only adhered to the "Catholic" church.  Insofar as "catholic" is understood as "universal" or "what most people think of when they think of ['mainstream' Christianity](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/a/888/1039), that is accurate.  If that were taken to mean the 'Roman Catholic Church,' that would be precise, but inaccurate, in that most Protestants and Orthodox also subscribe to the Creeds and to the Trinitarian formulations thereof.</sup>

**2. The nature of the "Bible"**

[Evangelicals consider the canon to be closed](http://bible.org/article/evangelicals-and-canon-new-testament). [Mormons have their own scriptures composed well after the period](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/12029/how-is-one-supposed-to-know-whether-or-not-the-book-of-mormon-is-true).

**3. The nature of soteriology**

[Evangelicals, by and large, believe salvation to be solely the gift of God](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Ephesians+2%3A8-9&version=NIV). We believe that all who are saved enter into eternal relationship with God. [Mormons believe that people are rewarded according to the nature of the covenant they believed](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/10237/what-is-the-plan-of-salvation-in-lds-theology).

Comment: Point 1 is incorrect.  Mormons hold a different view of the Godhead than the Trinitarian concept that Evangelicals believe, but in no way do they deny the divinity of Jesus.

Comment: Revised.  Agreed that the wording was poor.

Comment: Can you add to the first point that evangelicals believe there is one and only one God, that Jesus cannot be both divine and separate from the Father, because that would make more than one God.  Not one God for this world, but one God, period.  And the Spirit is also of that one God.

Comment: Do Evangelicals believe that GOD IS ONE for Christianity, Judaism, and the Moslem faith? But not for the LDS?

Comment: And which version of the Trintarian Creed do Evangelicals pronounce? The Roman Catholic, The Orthodox, The Anglican, The C of E, the Episcopalian, or something else?

Comment: @waeshael it is not that evangelicals think differently about the unity of the godhood depending on the religion- rather it is Mormons who think different than the rest of mainstream Christianity. Mormons reject the Trinity, and Mormons reject the idea that Jesus and the Father are the same person. Evangelicals on the other hand, reject Mormons because they deny all of the Creeds you mention (and by and large subscribe to all of them)

Comment: Mormons do not subscribe to the Nicene Creed, nor the Nicene/Constantinople Creed of the Roman Catholic Church. Orthodox Catholics do not profess the Nicene Creed as the Roman Catholics do. Now, if anyone believes the Nicene/Constatinople Creed of the RC Church is must be with the same understanding that the Church intends, otherwise it has no standing with the Church. In order to have a right understanding you would have to accept the RC Dogma. This is where the Mormons diverge.

Comment: Affable Geek: An Evangelical has no authority from God to reject anybody. Judge no man - Jesus said. Love one another, love my Brethren as I have loved you. And blessed are the peacemakers.

Comment: @Waeshael I think you are misunderstanding me - the question asked, how do Evangelicals and Mormons differ.  I attempted to give a summary. Whether or not Mormons are justified before God is completely irrelevant :)  I'm just trying to explain how an evangelical would react to a Mormon and vice versa.

Comment: Okay here is my experience as vestry member for evangelization at my ACC Church. When I meet a Mormon." I love them as brethren. I don't preach to them, or try to change their ideas. I have one or two LDS friends.

Comment: Point 2 is not clear (may i say radical?) enough imho. Evangelicals may find "additional scriptures" in opposition with their belief in a closed canon. The truth is, LDS do not consider the canon closed at all. Sure, we have additional scripture, but the main point here is we believe in continued revelation, or in other words, living prophets. The canon has last changed in the 70's as far as I am aware, but there are continously changes that are thought to be inspired by God. That being said, I see no need to change the point, I just wanted to clarify ;-)

Comment: I might change point 3 to say something like: `Mormons believe that people are rewarded according to the nature of the covenants they kept.` as we believe there are multiple covenants we can make with God, and it doesn't matter if you believe something but don't follow it. I'd also like to state that the LDS believe salvation is a gift from God, see https://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/6123/22319

Answer (score 1):

Christians believe the Bible and the traditional understanding of what the Bible teaches, as summarized through the centuries in the various creeds (Nicene Creed, Apostles' Creed, Westminster Confession, etc). All Christian denominations, both Catholic and Protestant, are united in the following beliefs taken directly from Biblical teachings:

- There is only one God, and there has only ever been one God, in the entire Universe
- This one God has revealed himself in three persons: Father, Son and Holy Spirit -- but these three are a unity (hence "tri-unity" or Trinity)
- Jesus of Nazareth is the human form taken by this one God when he came to Earth to live a perfect life and allow himself to be sacrificed for the sins of all men
- That through this sacrifice of Jesus, all men can be reconciled to God and have their sins forgiven, without any deserving efforts of their own
- There are many more, but this will serve to show some essential differences.

Mormonism differs from Christianity in that Joseph Smith, Brigham Young (and others) taught that there have been more recent gospels: the Book of Mormon, Doctrine & Convenants, Pearl of Great Price -- as well as all sermons preached by Smith and Young as recorded in the Journal of Discourses.

Further, the Mormon church teaches that the Bible is a lesser source, in that it has been "corrupted" and is essentially not the same as what was first written. ([This game](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_whispers), under a different name, "Post Office", is often used as an example of how/why that happened.) Therefore, Mormons say, it is more important to read/believe the latter teachings. However, Christians point to examples from archaeology, such as the 1947 Dead Sea scrolls discovery, in which most books of the Old Testament were discovered, dating back 100 years before the birth of Jesus. The book of Isaiah, for example, shows only 13 characters in question, none of which change the meaning of any phrase. On the other hand, the Book of Mormon (to compare apples with apples) even changes the identity of God in one of it's 3,900+ changes since it was first published in 1830. (Compare 1 Nephi 11:18 and 1 Nephi 11:21 with their originals in 1830. Knowing Mormon theology, you will know that "God" and the "Son of God" are Elohim and Jehovah, respectively. This is a significant, theology-altering, change.)

Over and above the Bible's teachings, and sometimes in conflict with the Bible's teachings, the Mormon leaders taught that:

- There is only one God -- for this world. Every world has its own God, and every temple-going Mormon male hopes and believes that one day he will be judged worthy to become a God. As such he will receive/create his own World and will populate it with spirit children.
- God was once a man, and therefore He also has a father (as does his father, as does his father, etc). Where this stops is not discussed in Mormon literature.
- All humans (including Jesus) pre-existed in the spirit world. Jesus, Lucifer, Mary and you are all spirit brothers and sisters. In the spirit world Jesus was known as "Jehovah", and the Father's name is "Elohim"
- Jesus was born to Elohim (God the Father) and the virgin Mary through normal physical relations.
- The Book of Mormon tells the story of a Jewish family (time of Abraham) that sailed across the world to settle in America. The American Indians discovered by Columbus are the descendants of these Semitic peoples.

There are a vast number of other differences between the teachings of Christianity and Mormonism. You may wish to investigate the following areas: polygamy (many wives), polytheism (many gods), archaeology, scripture, the nature of God, the Trinity, the history of Christianity.

Most Christians who have investigated the claims and teachings of Mormonism firmly state that there are virtually NO common essential beliefs between Christianity and Mormonism. This matter is confusing to many people because Mormon teachings use the same names/words as Christian sources, but with completely different meanings. For example, the Mormon Jesus is not at all like the Christian Jesus, although the Mormon Jesus is said to BE the Christian Jesus. However, if you compare their origins, what they claimed about themselves, and their position after death, you will see little resemblance. They are two totally different beings.

**Sources:**

[CRI - Mormonism](http://www.equip.org/category/mormonism/)

[Utah Lighthouse](http://www.utlm.org/navonlineresources.htm)

Comment: This answer is riddled with both trivial and gaping flaws. Many points mentioned are incorrect and are not even on matters of significant doctrine, but rather speculation both in and out of the LDS Church. Your sources are highly suspect of strong bias and guile, having agendas. In fact, the whole answer is spotted by a subjective perspective. See [Are Mormons Christians](http://mormon.org/faq/mormon-christian) for a more factual answer.

Comment: Please identify any point listed above and references will be provided from Mormon sources for that teaching. As for bias, Matt, was it not Joseph Smith himself who claimed that Elohim and Jehovah appeared to him and said that all Christian denominations "were wrong", that "their "professors were all corrupt", and "all their creeds were an abomination in his sight"? Is this not also what the Mormon church [teaches today](http://www.lds.org/scriptures/pgp/js-h/1.19)? *If not, please provide the names of a few mainstream Christian denominations that Mormons would say agree with Mormon theology.*

Comment: Before this escalätes, I need to point out that "who is right and who is wrong" is off-topic, not constructive, leads to debate that is OK in chat,  but not welcome on the main site.  See: the [help page](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/help), [How we are different than other sites?](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/1808/how-we-are-different-than-other-sites) and [What makes a good supported answer?](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/692/what-makes-a-good-supported-answer)

Comment: I don't have time to be on the chat, but in the interest of improving this answer, @MormonInvestigator feel free to [email me](http://mwholt.com/contact) and I'd be happy to suggest a few changes and tell you more about where I'm coming from. It will also be good for me to better understand your perspective.

Answer (score 0):

Q: practices on where they differ?
These practices are different to Evangelical groups.

All LDS adults are also Priests, and the responsibility for their neighbors is a covenantal promise. Everyone in the local Church has a Priest assigned to them and he visits the home every month to see if anything is needed, and reports back to the Bishop.

LDS live a life of Christ, as far as it is possible in this day and age. They are monitored by the brethren and warned if they stray from God's Will as it is defined by Scripture and by revelations of the Prophets.

None of the clergy is paid. As in the early Church, each person must support themselves with a job outside the Church.

The Church has a central authority. Everyone believes the same theology. There is no disagreement in the Church.

Comment: I agree with all of this, except to say that there is disagreement in the LDS church now, just as there was in Moses' and Christ's times.

Comment: Ah, things must have changed since I was there.

Comment: I think the All Enlisted group disagrees with many teachings.

Comment: I didn't like giving up tea, but I didn't disagree with the teaching. WHat do you mean by "All Enlisted" - I am not familiar with it.

Comment: "All LDS adults are also Priests"?  As I understand it, "the power of the Priesthood" is given by ordination. Formerly some races were excluded, but since 1978 my understanding is that "all worthy male members" are eligible to receive the priesthood. Women may said to be "covered" by the priesthood because of ordained members in their family, or even in their congregation, but they cannot be considered "priests". Evangelicals do generally believe in a "priesthood of all believers", some ordained and some not, but all having "power with God".

Comment: The "All Enlisted" group are women who requested the privilege of praying at an LDS General Conference meeting. http://www.prweb.com/releases/2013/1/prweb10337113.htm

Comment: @disciple Is that theology though? I agree, where there are people there will be disagreements, maybe what was meant is that there actually is a defined theology (let's say except where it's explicitly not defined yet)? My understanding is that Evangelical groups are very diverse in what they believe.